# PHP: Почему бд возврашает пустой ответ

Tags: mysql, php7

Я слелал класс для облегчения работы с бд:

```
class db_class{
public $dbi;
public function connect($server, $user, $pass, $name, $return = False){
    $connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $name);
    if(!$return){
        if(!$connect){
            echo "Ошибка подключения к БД.Код ошибки: " .mysqli_connect_error();
            Exit();
        }
    }else{
        $this->dbi = $connect;
    }
}
public function zapros($query){
    return mysqli_query($this->dbi, $query);
    mysqli_close($this->dbi);
}
}
```

И подключился к бд

```
$dbc = new db_class;
$dbc->connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "id1", True);
```

После, где-то в коде, хочу получить данные из бд, пишу

```
$result = $dbc->zapros("SELEECT * FROM users");
echo "Уже зарегестрировано:".$result->num_rows;

//$result это ответ бд
//$result->num_rows это количество найденого по запросу
```

Но БД возврашает пустую строку, как решить? И почему так происходит?
Я в php новичок, ещё учу.

Comment: А может, нельзя использовать mysql_query в классах, или $dbi не доходит до mysqli_query

Answer (score 0):

Есть совет: используйте IDE с возможностью Debug для пошагового прохождения вашего кода, чтобы увидеть поведении программы и где и куда что-то получается и отправляется (переменные);
Также сразу лучше использовать PDO и оффициальная документация поможет быстрее, так как там сразу дают примеры использования (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/).

```
public function zapros($query){
return mysqli_query($this->dbi, $query);
mysqli_close($this->dbi); //**Это строка никогда не выполниться**
```

}

например так:

```
  public function zapros($query){
    $result = mysqli_query($this->dbi, $query);
    mysqli_close($this->dbi);
    return $result;

}
```

Могу предположить, что как раз из-за  mysqli_close($this->dbi); не отрабатывает. Извините, проверить пока у себя не могу. Удачи в постижении PHP

Comment: Нет, не помог ваш код, попробую PDO, ну сначала скачаю IDE с Debug.

Comment: Попробуйте сначала официальный пример (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php). Если заработает, то внесите изменения в него для ваших условий (пошагово с проверкой). Если и это отработает, то обычно к тому моменту свою ошибку вы уже обнаружите

Comment: Я так делал, и оно работало, перелал в класс, и перестало

Comment: Да сейчас нашел -ваш код в процедурном стиле, здесь пример внизу в стиле ООП https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php. Также обратите внимание на замечания внизу страницы

Comment: Я вообще хотел под себя сделать, ну попробовать сделать свой класс mysql функций, для опыта, ну раз уж не выходит, тогда буду уже готовую использовать

Comment: Спасибо что попробовали помочь.

Comment: Так вы все правильно делаете, все (большинство) поверх официальных классов пишут оболочку для простого использования в своем проекте. А отказываться от идеи не стоит, через это вы быстрее поймете механизмы работы языка.